# stc12c5a60s2 similar code but typed in different PC not working in keil

Tags: keil, code

Is there any reason why the code typed in my friends pc(bottom) works properly while the code I typed in my pc(top) doesn't? Both doesn't seem to have any error when compiled on my PC, but when downloaded onto the STC12 board, the top code would ask for val1 and val2 but skips asking for the operator then spits out 0 as the result. I think it might be a text format issue on my PC, but I don't know how to fix it.

my code that doesn't work

```
#include<reg51.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main(void)
{
    int val1,val2,eq;
    char op;
    TMOD=0x21;
    SCON=0x52;
    TH1=253;
    TR1=1;

while(1)
{
    printf("\nValue 1");
    scanf("%d",&val1);
    printf("\nValue 2");
    scanf("%d",&val2);

    printf("\nOperation");
    scanf("%c",&op);

    if(op=='+')
    {
    eq=val1+val2;
    }

    if(op=='-')
    {
    eq=val1-val2;
    }

    if(op=='*')
    {
    eq=val1*val2;
    }

    if(op=='/')
    {
    eq=val1/val2;
    }

    printf("\nresult=%d",eq);
}

}
```

friend's code that works

```
#include<reg51.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main(void)
{
    int val1,val2,eq;
    char op;
    TMOD=0x21;
    SCON=0x52;
    TH1=253;
    TR1=1;
    
   while(1)
   {
    printf("\nPlease enter value 1 ");
    scanf("%d",&val1);
    printf("\nPlease enter value 2 ");
    scanf("%d",&val2);


    printf("\noperatation");
    scanf(" %c",&op);
    
    if(op=='+')
    {
    eq = val1+val2;
    }

    if(op=='-')
    {
    eq = val1-val2; 
    }

    if(op=='*')
    {
    eq = val1*val2;
    }

    if(op=='/')
    {
    eq = val1/val2;
    }

    printf("\nResult = %d",eq);

    
   }

}
```

Comment: This is not a Electrical Engineering problem, it's a C programming problem and belongs on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). But the different behavior is probably due to the different scanf format strings you and your friend are using. You're using `"%c"` while your friend is using `" %c"` - note the space.

Comment: have you diffed the two programs?

Comment: @brhans Alright. Thank you for the correction.